# Wildcard search on nested JSONB column including number data type

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath, postgresql-performance, postgresql-json

When searching a nested jsonb column in postgres we can do a full text search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM search_test u
WHERE items @? '$.** ? (@ like_regex "35" flag "i")';
```

This will return all rows in the table having string value containing "35" in items jsonb colum.

But how can we include number data type in this query? For instance if items column had this value:

```
{"id": "15351", "nid": 15751 }
```

How can we include the number data types in the query so that we would get a result from this:

```
SELECT * FROM search_test u
WHERE items @? '$.** ? (@ like_regex "75" flag "i")';
```

Tried to look for casting options but the only solution I've found so far is to create an additional column with the number values stored as string and then search both columns.

Here's a sample fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e5929ddbcf69ae3704da932b61a7d153

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract all key/value pairs, then apply the LIKE condition on each value using an EXISTS condition:

```
select s.*
from search_test s
where exists (select * 
              from jsonb_each_text(s.items) as x(k,v)
              where x.v like '%35%');
```

Comment: I doubt this will be performant and also I did not mention that the "items" jsonb column is nested so I updated the question with this information.

Comment: Yes, this won't be able to use an index - that's the price you pay for de-normalizing your data model

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM   search_test u
WHERE  items::text like '%75%';
```